# MySQL/PHP Admin: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table called reservation which stores the reservation details. When I try to create the table it gives me the error;

> Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

This is my query;

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `smartbusarrival_sbaDB`.`reservation` (
 `res_id` INT NOT NULL,
 `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
 `bus_id` INT NOT NULL,
 `trip_id` INT NOT NULL,
 `date` DATE NOT NULL, 
 `start` INT NOT NULL,
 `end` INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`res_id`),
 INDEX `fk_user_id` (`user_id` ASC),
 INDEX `fk_bus_id` (`bus_id` ASC),
 INDEX `fk_trip_id` (`trip_id` ASC),
 INDEX `fk_start` (`start` ASC),
 INDEX `fk_end` (`end` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_reservation_user`
   FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
   REFERENCES `smartbusarrival_sbaDB`.`users` (`id`)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_reservation_bustrip`
   FOREIGN KEY (`bus_id`,`trip_id`)
   REFERENCES `smartbusarrival_sbaDB`.`bustrip` (`bus_id`,`trip_id`)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_reservation_start`
   FOREIGN KEY (`start`)
   REFERENCES `smartbusarrival_sbaDB`.`trip_halt` (`tag`)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_reservation_end`
   FOREIGN KEY (`end`)
   REFERENCES `smartbusarrival_sbaDB`.`trip_halt` (`tag`)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

user_id is is a foreign from users table(primary key)

bus_id + trip_id is a composite key from bustrip table (primary key)

start and end are foreign key from trip_halt table.

I looked into similar questions but nothing solve my problem. Can anyone suggest something to solve this.
Thank You!!!

Comment: Are the fields of the same type ?

Comment: @Pooya Raki Yes. All the fields are same type (INT).

Comment: Your statement looks fine, but you probably are missing indexes in the referenced tables. From your description my best guess would be a missing index `trip_halt(tag)`, so either check that yourself or add the create statement for the table `trip_halt`. And just to check if it is really the right primary key, the create statement for the table `bustrip`.

Comment: @Solarflare I'm new to this. Can you elaborate this?

Comment: Execute the sql code `show create table trip_halt` (and maybe `show create table bustrip`) and add the result to your question. Or check in phpmyadmin if you have an index on `trip_halt(tag)` and add it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: thank you. it works now. tag field wasn't a unique one.

Comment: Actually, MySQL (in contrast to the sql standard) allows the referenced key to be non-unique. Since marking the column as unique in phpmyadmin will create that index, you did create the missing index, so it's fine now. Just make sure tag really IS supposed to be unique (it doesn't look like the primary key), otherwise you might get in trouble later on when you want to insert data.

Comment: Yeah that's could be a problem. It would be easy to handle my data if the tag is not unique. What can do to avoid that?

Comment: If your tag-column should be non-unique, you have two options: use the (unique) primary key of the `trip_halt`-table instead of the `tag` column for the reference, or, in phpmyadmin, instead of "unique", click on "index", and remove the unique index again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the field you are referencing as a foreign key should be a unique. I think 'tag' field is not a unique one.